# Un-assign macros from all the checkboxes in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have an `excel` spreadsheet with more than 700 checkboxes. All the checkboxes have been assigned to one particular macro. I have deleted this macro. Now, I want to unassign this macro from all the checkboxes. I can do it for one checkbox manually by deleting the text when clicking on `assign Macro`. But how can I do this for large number of checkboxes? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each CheckBox In sht.CheckBoxes
        CheckBox.Select
        CheckBox.OnAction = ""
    Next CheckBox
Next sht
```

There should be a better way than simply assigning it to "" but this definitely works

Comment: It gives an error: "Unable to set the OnAction property of the CheckBox class"

Comment: The code will work ONLY if checkbox is selected. So, requires extra line before action deletion: CheckBox.Select

Comment: Edited the code to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

If you `Ctrl` + `Click` one of the check marks and then press `Ctrl` + `A` it will select them all. From there you can edit formatting, macros and so on...

Comment: Thanks, this is a simpler solution indeed. If I had to unassign macro for some of the checkboxes and not all, this would be perfect.